# How to handle any error during Homekit Pairing

Tags: swift3, ios10

How to use the given method in swift 3.

func addAndSetupAccessories(completionHandler completion: (Error?) -> Void)

I observed, the completion handler got invoked immediately although the HomeKit set up page(very initial page of Homekit accessory pairing in iOS 10) was front and the accessory pairing process was not over. If this is the case, how to invoke any operation after the set up process gets completed? How to get if the set up process is over??

Comment: Managed to handle the completion by using the delegate method 'func home(_ home: HMHome, didAdd accessory: HMAccessory)'. Once the accessory is added, this method is invoked. For this to work, we need to set  our object as the HMHomeDelegate of the HMHome.

Comment: iOS 10.3 changed this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to handle it is to assign a `HMHomeDelegate` to the target `HMHome` object before calling `addAndSetupAccessories` and keep track of accessories that are added. The dialog only allows setting up one accessory at a time, so you will get at most one non-bridged accessory and potentially zero or more bridged accessories.

When your view controller that is hosting the process gets `viewDidAppear` called the second time, check if you have set up a non-bridged accessory. If not, it was either cancelled, or finished with an error, which Apple's dialog would have already handled.

Note that **this will not work on iPad** as it shows a popup, so `viewDidAppear` won't be called when pairing dialog is dismissed. I'm not sure it's possible at all to find out when the process finishes on iPad.

**UPDATE**

iOS 10.3 completely changes this behaviour, and the completion handler of `addAndSetupAccessories` is now invoked when the pairing dialog is closed (as it should have been to begin with). If nothing was paired, the callback will get an error with code 23, `HMError.operationCancelled`.

You still have to keep track of added accessories via `HMHomeDelegate` callback, but post-setup handling should move from `viewWillAppear` to the `addAndSetupAccessories` callback.

To the surprise of no one it's not documented or mentioned anywhere in any release notes.